# Data loader field missing while mapping

Tags: data-loader, data

Data Loader is not showing up the field for mapping . I checked the field accessibility and the field is read only. Why is the field not available for mapping?

Comment: What operation are you performing? What field is it? Please **[edit]** your post to be more specific.

Comment: Did you just modified the Field Level Permissions (After Login into the Data Loader), If yes, then you need to log out and login again.

Comment: You can't map into read-only fields. They're read only.

Comment: I am trying to perform an update operation . The field was not on the page layout so I added it to the page layout  . My field is pick list , i checked the field accessibility and it is read only for my profile but still not visible when I can able to map in data loader

Comment: @sfdcfox: Any work around for this?

Comment: @Sumanth You need to make the field editable for your profile, then log out of the data loader and log back in to the Data Loader.

Comment: @sfdcfox: I dont think I have the access to make it editible and log out and log in back is necessary into the data loader?

Comment: I was able to make the field editable for my profile , added the field in the page layout but still the field is  not showing up in the data loader.

Comment: @sfdcfox Please create an answer :) I've found this question once again, and fortunately I just had to follow my up-votes. But this one deserves to have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Data Loader won't allow read-only fields to be mapped. Make sure the field is editable to the user's profile. If you change field permissions, you need to log out of the Data Loader and log in again.